# JVM Minor gc is not triggered until both Eden and one of Surviror areas are full

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, eden

I encountered a weird phenomenon when testing my app on JVM. I found that after an evening's lasting running, the JVM's Minor gc will not be triggered unless both Eden and one of survior areas is full. Just like photos below.
[jstat -gcutil1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nNq8.png)

[jstat -gcutil2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLZK1.png)

I'm using Alibaba DragonWell Open JDK:
openjdk version "1.8.0_322"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Alibaba Dragonwell 8.10.11) (build 1.8.0_322-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Alibaba Dragonwell 8.10.11) (build 25.322-b01, mixed mode)

So are there some experts could explain the reasons for this problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to specify which collector you're using and also label the columns of the attached tables of numbers. Also, is this causing any issues or are you just curious?

Comment: Your conclusion makes no sense. The only way, a survivor area can become full, is by having an actual garbage collection which moves objects from Eden into the Survivor area. So it is impossible to only have a garbage collection when one of survivor areas is full. That would be a chicken-and-egg problem.